# How to transfer data from ajax to laravel 5.2 controller via mail method

Tags: laravel

I want to transfer data to the controller using ajax. Here is the ajax code

```
$(document).on("click", '#bt1', function(e)
{
 e.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
     url:"/insert_",
     type:"post",
     data:{
         name2:"admin",
         _token: $("input[name='_token']").val()
     }
  })
});
```

Here is the code in the controller

```
public function insert_db(Request $request)
{
   $a1=$request->input("name2");
   dd($a1);
}
```

Here is the layout code

```
<form action="/insert_" method="post">
@csrf
<input type="submit" id="bt1" value="do it">
```

Here is code в web.php

```
Route::post('/insert_',"StudentController@insert_db");
```

if i will write in controller this code

```
dd($request->all());
```

then displays this[image]

Comment: Is the request send to the server? Please check your DevTools for this and any errors on the request that is send.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for debugging use `dd($request->all())` instead of trying to display only some value.
But your problem seems to be because you are using `$request->input('name2')`. But you don't have an input at your front-end, you are sending this value through AJAX parameter. So, instead, try to call `$request->name2`.

Comment: if i use $request->name2, display error. Are you sure that need 
exactly just so write?

Comment: Why you don't post this error here, so we will save some hours on waiting it from you again? 
First, make `dd($request->all())` and post here the output. If this `name2` key  and his value persists, it means that everything is ok and you are just calling this key in the wrong way.
So, if `dd` will show it, logically, you can access them with `$request->name2` or may be even with `$request->input('name2');`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any thing wrong here!
try to `dd($request->all())` to check for submitted variables!
if variable `name2` was available there, then try to get variable with

```
$request->name2
```

OR

```
 $request->`your_variable_name`
```

Comment: if i use $request->name2 , displays error. Are you sure that need exactly just so write?

Comment: try to put your variable names on quotation (e.g `"name2":"your data"`) and check it again.